# Another Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps

It must say something about Google Maps API that similar questions come up so often. But I've read all the previous ones, and couldn't find anything to solve my problem.

I have a Google Map working successfully (after a lot of pain and experimentation) on one website. There the map opens in a floatbox. Now I am trying to transfer it to another website where it will open in a div in the parent page. I've copied the code across, but am completely bogged down by "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined" errors.

More specifically the Chrome console reports:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)), <anonymous>:1:959)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:1:1)
at eval (<anonymous>)
at jquery.min.js:2
at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
at text script (jquery.min.js:4)
at Xb (jquery.min.js:4)
at y (jquery.min.js:4)
at c (jquery.min.js:4)
at Object.send (jquery.min.js:4)
```

There is no jquery call in the map file so it presumably refers back to the parent page which does use jquery for various stuff, including opening the map with

```
$("#mapsee").click(function(){
     $("#mapsee").hide();
     $("#maphide").show();
     $("#mapspace").slideDown(2000, function() {
        $("#mapspace").load("/includes/map_hotel_dev.php?hid=<?php echo $row_hotel['hid'] ?>");
    });
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#mapspace").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

My Google Maps script on map_hotel_dev.php is

```
<script>
function initMap() {
var map;

  var image = {
      url: '../images/hotel_grey_icon.gif',
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 35)
  };
  var hotelimage = {
      url: '../images/hotel_bigicon.gif',
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 37)
      };

function createMarker(point, html) {
var timer;
var html;
var contentString = html;
        var ibOptions = {
         content: contentString
        ,closeBoxMargin: "-8px"
        ,disableAutoPan: true
        ,enableEventPropagation: false
        ,alignBottom: true
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-120, -36)
};
var ib = new InfoBox(ibOptions);

if(point.equals(thisLatlng)){
    var thisicon = hotelimage;
    var zed = 9999;
}else{
    var thisicon = image;
    var zed = Math.round(point.lat()*-100000)<<5
}
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: thisicon,
    zIndex: zed
});

marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
    ib.open(map, marker);
    }, 500);
});marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    ib.open(map, marker);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    ib.close(map, marker);
});

}

var lat = <?php echo $row_hotel['latitude'] ?>;
var lng = <?php echo $row_hotel['longitude'] ?>;
var zoom = 10;
var thisLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var mapOptions = {
center: thisLatlng,
zoom: zoom,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   streetViewControl: true,
   scaleControl: true,
   zoomControl: true
   }

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), mapOptions);


var style_nopoi = [{"featureType": "poi.business", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}]; // Styles, removes business points-of-interest. Lots of other possibilities.
map.setOptions({styles: style_nopoi});  // Applies the style to the map

var loadcnt = 0;
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
        if (loadcnt==0) {
        map.setCenter(thisLatlng); // Seems to fix random centring problem on mobiles
        loadcnt=loadcnt+1;
        }
        });

downloadUrl("/includes/php-to-xml.php?iso=<?php echo $row_hotel['countryisocode'] ?>", function(doc) {
var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
    var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var html=markers[i].getAttribute("html");
    createMarker(point, html);
}

});
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=quarterly&key=MYKEY&callback=initMap"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/infobox.js"></script>
```

I've tried all manner of possible solutions: async loading, defer, putting the API and infobox scripts at the top of the page, and even transferring the API script to the parent page. Now I've just about run out of ideas.

A similar script using infowindow instead of infobox works fine. While testing I tried the old (infowindow) script with the addition of the infobox call and I immediately get the Uncaught ReferenceError so I suspect that is where the problem is in some way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I finally found the solution so for anyone else who comes along later, this is how I resolved it.

My mistake was to try to load a separate file (map_hotel_dev.php) into the div in the parent page. I copied the code from map_hotel_dev.php into the parent page and then changed to jquery to open the map to this:

```
$("#mapsee").click(function(){
     $("#mapsee").hide();
     $("#maphide").show();
     $("#mapspace").slideDown(2000, function() {
        initMap();
    });
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#mapspace").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Now it all works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

API is not getting loaded hence google undefined, can you remove the v=quarterly?

Use URL from documentation please

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap